# How can I pass a variable from function to function in Python (Kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, variables, kivy

I am having an issue in my code where I am trying to take user input from `self.ids.email.text` and `self.ids.password.text` and pass their values into variables named email and password. Then the program is supposed to verify that the credentials match and sign-in. Here is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Window.clearcolor = 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1
Window.size = 414, 736

# Chase Weaver

# Display Offline Label Variable
onlineStatus = 1

class PulseWelcome(Screen):
    pass

    class PulseWelcomeCanvas(Widget):
        pass

class PulseLogin(Screen):

    def emailRecord(self):
        global email
        email = self.ids.email.text
#        print(email)
        return email

    def passwordRecord(self):
        global password
        password = self.ids.password.text
#        print(password)
        return password

    def signIn(self): 

        global email
        global password

        if email == 'email@email.com' and password == '123pass':
            sm.transition.direction = 'up'
            sm.current = 'home'
            print('CHECK')
        else:
            print('FAIL')

    class PulseLoginCanvas(Widget):
        pass

class PulseHome(Screen):

    def updateStatus(self):

        global onlineStatus

        if onlineStatus == 1:
            self.ids.offline_label.text = ''

        else:
            self.ids.offline_label.text = 'No friends Online'

    class PulseHomeCanvas(Widget):
        pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class PulseApp(App):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(PulseWelcome(name = 'welcome'))
        sm.add_widget(PulseLogin(name = 'login'))
        sm.add_widget(PulseHome(name = 'home'))
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PulseApp().run()
```

After running this code, I am given the error: `NameError: name 'email' is not defined. Did you mean: 'eval'?`

I have tried using `return` and `global` to pass the variables and their values to each function but no luck. Any ideas on how I could fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to study the scope of the variables.

The `global email` indicates that you should look for the variable in your entire file, but it doesn't mean that it exists.
For them to be truly global you should do something like this:

```py
# Optional
email: str
password: str

class A:
    def func_A(self):
        # Necessary to indicate that global variables
        # are modified / created and thus not to create local variables
        global email, password 
        
        print("Do some stuff")
        email = "A value"
        password = "Another Value"

class B:
    def func_B(self):
        # Optional, the resolver seeing that in the current
        # scope (the function, then the class) the variables
        # do not exist, then it will go in the scope still higher (global)
        global email, password
        
        print("Do some other stuf")
        print(email, password)


A = A()
B = B()

A.func_A()
B.func_B()

print(email, password)
```

But I don't think it's a good idea for what you do. It might be better to change your architecture

Comment: I will try what you suggested. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to read this kind of [page](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp) and indicate an answer as a solution if this is the case